# Getting a specific row in a spritesheet libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to access a specific row in my sprite sheet and I am thoroughly confused as to how to do this. I tried modifying a tutorial I found to accomplish this but when I run the code the length of my animation array is of size 0 when there are five rows in my spritesheet and 12 columns. My class should always fill my animation array with one row of information. Here is my `Animator` class

```
    public Animator(Texture spriteSheet, int cols){
    this.walkSheet = spriteSheet;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.rows = 1;
}

public void create() {
      TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet, walkSheet.getWidth()/cols, walkSheet.getHeight()/rows);              // #10
      walkFrames = new TextureRegion[cols];
      anim = new Animation[rows];
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
          walkFrames[j] = tmp[i][j];
        }
        anim[i] = new Animation(0.025f, walkFrames);
      }
      stateTime = 0f;                         // #13
    }

public void render(int index, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    currentFrame = anim[index].getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, x, y, width, height);
}
```

Any help with this will be extremely appreciated as I have spent so much time trying to figure this out.

Comment: You specified rows = 1 and you have 5 rows right? May I ask why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this code yet, but I think this could work for what you want.

```
public Animator(Texture spriteSheet, int cols, int rows){
    this.walkSheet = spriteSheet;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.rows = rows;
}

public void create() {
      TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet, walkSheet.getWidth()/cols, walkSheet.getHeight()/rows);              // #10
      anim = new Animation[rows];
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       walkFrames = new TextureRegion[cols];
       for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
          walkFrames[j] = tmp[i][j];
        }
      anim[i] = new Animation(0.025f, walkFrames);
      }
      stateTime = 0f;                         // #13
    }

public void render(int index, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    currentFrame = anim[index].getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, x, y, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You're my hero !

Comment: Why does the TextureRegion have to be instantiated every loop? The Animation class creates a new TextureRegion for each frame in the constructor.

Comment: Interesting, what else did you change that got it working? I came up with the create() method here in a previous question he asked. All I see is `this.rows = rows;` instead of 1

Comment: I don't know, I just programmed it the way I thought it would work. Hahaha Maybe it was that 1.